# CSS3 transition only applying to active link, and not all links

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, transition

On [my site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/contact/) ( 1 ) Im trying to add this transition to all of my nav links, but i can only get it to work for the visited link. ( 2 ) Im trying to add this transition to the drop down menus.

```
body .main-nav .active-link >a, body .main-nav .active-link >a:visited {
border-top: solid 0px #3b5998;
color: #3b5998;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out }
```

Comment: its a template based site from squarespace, i dont know how, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect selector if you need all of the links to have transition.

It should be:

```
body .main-nav li >a, body .main-nav li >a:visited
```

You have `.active-link` in your selector which exists only to the link of the page you are on.

Comment: can you help me apply this transition to my drop down folders in the nav?  currently have :#header #topNav nav .folder ul li{padding:0 24px 12px; position:relative; }

Comment: @JeffDowell hey why don't you use? : `#topNav li { // transition code here }` If you want to use transition for only dropdown list elements, it can be: `#topNav li.folder ul > li { // transition code here }`

Comment: i added that in, but it doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: @JeffDowell oh! add `body #header` before `#topNav li { // transition code here }`

Comment: i may have not asked my question correctly. I would like the menu (white box and text fade in)